# Resource Lock and the Power Shell

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell, resources

is there a way to use the windows power shell to trace what application has a resource lock on a file?

Here is what i am looking for:

- A command line or script to show the application that has a lock on a file.
- A bonus to the above wold be detection of the user account that has the lock and how long the lock has persisted.

Follow up:

- There is a power tool by [SysInternals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958123/powershell-script-to-check-application-thats-locking-a-file) that will allow you to capture a full dump in the command shell of the above.
- I found a script that appears to do the job as well (replace  with the full path and file you want to see):

  PS> $handle = handle

  PS> foreach ($line in $handle) { 
          if ($line -match '\S+\spid:') {
              $exe = $line
          } 
          elseif ($line -match '')  { 
              "$exe - $line"
          }
       }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) from Windows Sysinternals is a command line utility that can be used to determine what handles have a lock on a file. You can run handle from the command line with

```
handle c:\fileToCheck
```

Or you could write a PowerShell script to wrap the functionality of handle.

Comment: I just found the same thing and updated the post with the script. Thanks.